# c# truly H-I-D-E files

Tags: hidden-files

We know that by this code we can hide a file:

```
File.SetAttributes(path, FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

But the problem is that you can see these kind of hidden files by choosing "Show hidden files, folders, and drivers" in Folder Options in Windows Control Panel.
How can we make a file (like a .mkv file) hidden which can only be seen by our programs permission?
Thanks!

Comment: It is not possible on windows in file level. In directory level, you can set the permisiion for one windows user. But all other users will see this directory, but they cannot step into